# PDF Merge VB.NET using search words as Arrays. The Code is working but duplicating the 1st PDF?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, pdf, directory, pdfsharp

I wrote this code that searches for 2 different PDF files based on the filename containing a specific word.

In my case i'm searching for "Complaint" and "Exhibit".

I thought about finding these words using a search function and contains().

So i'll have a directory that has

ZTEST10 Complaint.pdf (2 pages)

ZTEST10 Exhibit.pdf (2 pages)

The output file name of them merging is ZTEST10 Complaint & Exhibit.pdf.

Only thing is within the pdf Complaint comes out twice?  Example:

Complaint page 1

Complaint page 2

Complaint page 1

Complaint page 2

Exhibit page 1

Exhibit page 2

I have no idea why my code is duplicating the first PDF it finds?

Here is my code:

```
 Private inputdir1 = ("G:\Word\Department Folders\Pre-Suit\Drafts-IL\2-IL_AttyReview\2018-09\Reviewed\unmerged\Merge\")
    Sub Main()
        Dim OutputFile As String
        Dim OutputDir As String = inputdir1
        Dim OutputDocument As PdfDocument
        Dim Array = {"Complaint", "Exhibit"}
        For Each Ar In Array
            Dim element = Ar

            For Each files As IO.FileInfo In Get_Files(inputdir1,
                                              IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly,
                                              "pdf",
                                              element)


                Console.WriteLine(files)
                Console.WriteLine("Merging: {0}...", GetFileName(files.Name))


                For Each fileinput As String In Directory.GetFiles(inputdir1, files.Name)


                    OutputFile = GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileinput).Substring(0, 7) & " Complaint & Exhibit" & ".pdf"
                    If File.Exists(OutputDir & OutputFile) Then
                        OutputDocument = PdfReader.Open(OutputDir & OutputFile)
                    Else
                        OutputDocument = New PdfDocument()
                    End If

                    Using InputDocument As PdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(fileinput, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)
                        For Each page As PdfPage In InputDocument.Pages
                            OutputDocument.AddPage(page)

                        Next
                    End Using

                    OutputDocument.Save(OutputDir & OutputFile)
                    OutputDocument.Dispose()
                Next
            Next
        Next




    End Sub
    Private Function Get_Files(ByVal directory As String,
                           ByVal recursive As IO.SearchOption,
                           ByVal ext As String,
                           ByVal with_word_in_filename As String) As List(Of IO.FileInfo)

        Return IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*" & If(ext.StartsWith("*"), ext.Substring(1), ext), recursive) _
                           .Where(Function(o) o.ToLower.Contains(with_word_in_filename.ToLower)) _
        .Select(Function(p) New IO.FileInfo(p)).ToList

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: What are the classes `PdfDocument`, `PdfReader`, `PdfPage` about? They look like iText 7 classes, but I don't recognize the rest of the syntax.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie They're from PdfSharp.Pdf

Comment: In that case you should tag your question accordingly.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the Output file is created too early, so the output file is copied to itself later on, thus duplicating one of the input files.

Change `" Complaint & Exhibit"` to e.g. `" Combined"` and check if the issue is solved.

Comment: Wow... i can't believe thats what it was...So it was basically iterating itself Finding Complaint, then Complaint & Exhibit thus making Complaint-Complaint & exhibit.

So this solved it.  But my question would be.. would it be possible to have the output named "Complaint & Exhibit" without it duplicating itself by searching it self?  Is this because the files are within the same directory?  Or perhaps i could have the Original pdf's deleted once they are merged?

Comment: One option: save the file once when you are done (keep it in memory until then). Another option: use a different output directory. Third option: use a temporary file name and rename it when all files where processed, maybe keeping all file names in memory.